# Passing field values from one page to the next with Freeform Pro

Tags: forms, solspace-freeform

I'm using Freeform Pro 4 and creating a multipage form. In the first page I have a field {freeform:field:sale_price} where the user can enter a price for their house.

On the next page I then need to do some calculations on this price.

I know that there is also a Hidden Field type, so I created a 'sale_price_hidden' and then when the user submits the first page, the hidden value gets added like so;

```
<input type="hidden" name="sale_price_hidden" value="{freeform:field:sale_price}{freeform:data:value}{/freeform:field:sale_price}" />
```

On the second page I am then trying to retrieve that value, but I'm not sure how to get the raw data value (assuming it is possible).

Wondered if someone could help? :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Freeform Pro has the {freeform:mp_data:FIELD_NAME} tag to assist with items like this:

http://www.solspace.com/docs/freeform/form#freeform_mp_data_field_name

Comment: Hey Greg. Thanks for this. Unfortunately it just shows the field with the value, rather then just the raw value. :(

Comment: It shouldn't be, what does your template look like?

Comment: Ah. I think it was because I had tried using hidden fields which screwed things up. Removed the hidden field and then on the second page I'm now just using the {freeform:mp_data:sale_price} which works fine. :)

Comment: Just discovered the bug with 4.0.10 when it displays something like this freehold|~|Freehold when trying to get a value from a Select. I understand that there might be a patch for this before the next release?

Comment: Hey, sorry I didn't see this. Alerts aren't working for me. We are testing a version 4.0.11 for release that fixes this issue.

Comment: Hey Greg. No worries, I've had issues with alerts on here too. Look forward to the next update. Cheers.